# Nodejs nightmare iterate

Tags: javascript, node.js, nightmare

i have this code block,

```
var click_data = ['.click-fgdfc', '.click-f55gc', '.click-dfgc', '.click-fg45c', '.click-fg34c'];

nightmare

  .goto(site)
  .click('#cookieUsagePopIn .closeBtn')
  .wait(1000)
  .click('[for=acceptContract]')
  .click('#submitButton')
  .wait('.myAccount')
  .goto(site)
  .wait(1000)
  .click(click_data[0])
  .wait(1000)
  .click('.logoutBtn')
  .wait('.btnSignUp')

  .end()
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('error: ', error)
  });
```

and i want to iterate part of the code,

```
  .goto(site)
  .click('#cookieUsagePopIn .closeBtn')
  .wait(1000)
  .click('[for=acceptContract]')
  .click('#submitButton')
  .wait('.myAccount')
  .goto(site)
  .wait(1000)
  .click(click_data[0])
  .wait(1000)
  .click('.logoutBtn')
  .wait('.btnSignUp')
```

because i should use click_data array like `click_data[0], click_data[1]` (maybe a counter usable for this like `click_data[count]`).

And, it should stop when click_data[20] is present.

Comment: Where does click_data array come from?

Comment: i added this variable to my thread.

Comment: What happens when you wrap the entire block in a foreach?

Comment: @ericH nightmare module gives error.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "iterate part of the code?" It's not clear what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

Those are chainables. It's the return value of one call that serves as the object for the subsequent call.  So you can refactor `a.b().c().d()` into `p=a.b(); p=p.c(); p=p.d();`  and therefore, if you wanted to loop `c()` 5 times to simulate `a.b().c().c().c().c().c().d()`

do this:

```
var p = a.b();
for (let i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
  p = p.c();
}
p = p.d();
```

Comment: @ODYN-Kon's answer uses this approach with your code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to do something like this.

```
var click_data = ['.click-fgdfc', '.click-f55gc', '.click-dfgc', '.click-fg45c', '.click-fg34c'];
click_data.map(data => {

nightmare

  .goto(site)
  .click('#cookieUsagePopIn .closeBtn')
  .wait(1000)
  .click('[for=acceptContract]')
  .click('#submitButton')
  .wait('.myAccount')
  .goto(site)
  .wait(1000)
  .click(data)
  .wait(1000)
  .click('.logoutBtn')
  .wait('.btnSignUp')

  .end()
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('error: ', error)
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.  You'll have to adapt it a bit for your code.

```
// index.js

const Nightmare = require('nightmare');

const nightmare = Nightmare({ show: true });
const clickData = ['#doc-info', '#cst'];

clickData.reduce((accumulator, selector) => {
    return accumulator.then((results) => {
        return nightmare.goto('https://google.com')
            .wait('body')
            .click(selector)
            .title()
            .then((result) => {
                results.push(result);
                return results;
            });
    });
}, Promise.resolve([]))
    .then((results) => {
        console.dir(results);
    })
    .then(nightmare.end)
    .catch(nightmare.end);
```